# How should one refer to the algorithm similar to Gaussian elimination whose output is a lower-triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

As I was surfing the web, I found that there is not only back substitution, but also forward substitution. As opposed to back substitution, forward substitution takes as input an augmented matrix, of which the left block is lower-triangular and not upper-triangular and outputs the row equivalent matrix whose left block is diagonal. What's the name of the method that allows to produce an output acceptable by a forward substitution algorithm?

Comment: I've skimmed through these notes, yet couldn't find what I was looking for. To clarify, I am trying to find a name of an algorithm that I applied. The solution using the combination of this algorithm followed by forward substitution required in my case only 2 elementary row operations, that's why I would love to know how to refer to it.